# Where would I place this code for it to work with Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am having a problem with my code and I have figured out how to make something change the background color of if a word is present on the website, but I am not sure where and how to make it work with a google extension that in the mainfest makes the script bellow run every time the website is open. I was thinking of putting the code into inject.js but this seams to not work although when I tested the code in console it was working fine for every occasion I tested. I am not sure if I am putting the code into the wrong file but if you could give me some pointers or help I would be grateful.

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('Block')[0];
var originalHtml = element.innerHTML;
var newHtml = originalHtml.replace(new RegExp("Game", "g"), "<p style='background-color: lightblue;'>Game</p>");
element.innerHTML = newHtml;
```

Ps the block is a line by line set of words, that sometimes has game or No game and I just want to change the color of one of the variables so that I can see clearly the distribution of game to no game.

Answer (score 1):

You should write your code in contentscript. e.g. content.js and have entry in manifest file like

```
"content_scripts": [
        {
        "matches": [
            "http://*/*",
            "https://*/*"
            ],
        "js": ["content.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"    // Pay attention to this line
        }
    ]
```

so whenever your page loads at document end event your script runs.